# symfony: set secure flag dynamically over filter class

Tags: security, symfony1, set, dynamic

I want to decide dynamically if an application is secure or not.
Is it possible to set the secure flag (which is normaly set in security.yml) over a filter class?

Thx for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

To manage the user credentials, sfBasicSecurityUser provides several methods:

```
// Add one or more credentials
$user->addCredential('foo');
$user->addCredentials('foo', 'bar');

// Check if the user has a credential
echo $user->hasCredential('foo');                      =>   true

// Check if the user has both credentials
echo $user->hasCredential(array('foo', 'bar'));        =>   true

// Check if the user has one of the credentials
echo $user->hasCredential(array('foo', 'bar'), false); =>   true

// Remove a credential
$user->removeCredential('foo');
echo $user->hasCredential('foo');                      =>   false

// Remove all credentials (useful in the logout process)
$user->clearCredentials();
echo $user->hasCredential('bar');                      =>   false
```

Source: [Practical symfony - day 13 - The User](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/13#chapter_13_sub_authorization)

In your action you have access to user object with a getUser() method:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
```